# Jackson YAML Error: TSFBuilder class not found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jackson, yaml

I tried to write a string to a YAML file using Jackson (fasterxml), I created a Maven Java project using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. Then I edited the pom.xml as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"\>
<modelVersion\>4.0.0\</modelVersion\>

    <groupId>org.merkgames</groupId>
    <artifactId>ChatGPT</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.16.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.16.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
```

And in the Main.java file, I changed the Main method to look like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        String yamlString = "test: 1";
        Map<String, String> map = objectMapper.readValue(yamlString, Map.class);
    
        File file = new File("example.yml");
        objectMapper.writeValue(file, map);
    
    }
```

The following error occurred when running the file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TSFBuilder
at org.merkgames.Main.main(Main.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TSFBuilder
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone help me?

See above. Everything is listed there.

Comment: I guess you have to use the same version for all jackson dependencies, jackson-dataformat-yaml should have 2.16.0 too.

Answer (score 0):

Your jackson-dataformat-yaml is outdated.
Update it to 2.16.0 and app should run.